# PostGIS Nearest Neighbour outside buffer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, buffer, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to find the 6 nearest neighbours to a point which are outside a defined buffer.

Basically I am comparing points of the same table and working with [Mike Gleason's examples](http://geeohspatial.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/k-nearest-neighbor-search-in-postgis.html).

```
WITH subq AS (
SELECT p.id, p.name, unnest(ARRAY(SELECT q.name 
  FROM w_point q 
  where p.id != q.id
  ORDER BY ST_Buffer(p.geom, 0.1) <#> q.geom LIMIT 5)) as name
FROM w_point p)
SELECT * FROM subq;
```

The problem is, that the resulting points are still inside the buffer:
[image]
*Desired points are outside the yellow buffer, the table reflects the result*

How can I add the buffer to my query? Am I thinking the wrong way and is there a better one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to exclude the intersection of the buffer in the where clause.

```
WITH subq AS (
  SELECT p.id, p.name, 
    unnest(ARRAY(SELECT q.name 
      FROM w_point q  
      WHERE p.id != q.id AND NOT ST_Intersects(q.geom, ST_Buffer(p.geom, 0.1))
      ORDER BY ST_Buffer(p.geom, 0.1) <#> q.geom LIMIT 5)
    ) as name
   FROM w_point p
 )
 SELECT * FROM subq;
```

**EDIT:** It is more efficient to use ST_DWithin than ST_Buffer, so the above can better be written as,

```
WITH subq AS (
 SELECT p.id, p.name, 
    unnest(ARRAY(SELECT q.name 
      FROM w_point q  
      WHERE p.id != q.id and not ST_DWithin(q.geom, p.geom, 0.1)
      ORDER BY p.geom <#> q.geom LIMIT 5)
     ) as name
  FROM w_point p
 )
 SELECT * FROM subq;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed. I changed the `order by` to `p.geom <-> q.geom` because the second buffer is not needed anymore.

Comment: I was about to add that :D. Also I think it would be more efficient to use not ST_DWithin than buffer, in terms of index use. I will write up when I get home